# Error while login into Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

I planned to learn titanium framework, hence i have installed the appcelerator in my windows 7, 64-bit system.

while login in to appcelerator it is giving error "ERROR | The registry service is currently unavailable". for the same you can see the attachment.

Appreciate your response in advance.

Regards

Ravindra Ganni

Appcelerator login screen error message

Comment: Did you try to resolve using the CLI troubleshooting guide? http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are behind a proxy/firewall?

This guide shows you how to handle that:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Using_Studio_From_Behind_a_Proxy